# Maximum recipes MAKE runs?

Tags: makefile

As I was going through kernel compilation, I came across `-j` option on make for parallel execution. It is said in [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) that `make runs as many recipes simultaneously as possible`.

```
I was wondering, there should be a maximum limit for parallel execution.
Does it depend upon the cores ??
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be very clear: make (at least GNU make) is not multithreaded.  However, because make doesn't actually do any work (it starts other programs to do that work) it can still run multiple jobs in parallel: while make itself proceeds in a single-threaded manner it starts other programs and lets them run in the background while it continues to look for more jobs to start.

Make has no concept of "number of cores".  If you give `-j` without any argument, make will just start jobs until it can find no more jobs that can be started: that is, until there are no more targets in the makefile which can be built independently of each other.  In a large build environment this can very easily cause your entire system to go down in flames; trying to build the Linux kernel with `-j` with no restrictions, for example, is basically a fork-bomb.

In general you should always give an argument to `-j`.

One option: you might want to use `-j` (no arguments) alongside `-l` (restrict jobs based on system load).  This will allow you to run as many jobs as possible as long as the system load is not higher than some value.  This is useful but not very exact, as make can start jobs a *lot* faster than the system can recognize changes in the load.  There are some tricks in the code to try to mitigate this; it's worth a try.

Of course you can always give both a maximum number of jobs with `-jN` *and* a maximum system load with `-l`.

Answer (score 1):

The number of maximum *actual* parallel executions is given by the number of cores.

However, *make* splits the computation on a given number of threads, which can be even higher than the number of available cores. In this case, more than one thread is executed by the same core, and the execution is not actually parallel (it is just multi-threaded, which means that more threads are run concurrently by the same core, giving the illusion of parallel execution).

Usually, given N number of cores, it is a good practice to set -j equal to N+1